# Cannot capture sandbox PayPal payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently trying the [Orders API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) of PayPal using Postman, but cannot capture any payment.

For now, I could get the access token, set it to a collection variable, then created orders using (note the access token is set in the Authorization tab):

```
POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders

Body:
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "10.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The request was successful with response body:

```json
{
    "id": "<random-id>",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=<random-id>",
            "rel": "approve",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>",
            "rel": "update",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>/capture",
            "rel": "capture",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I proceeded to `rel:approve`'s link using a browser `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=<random-id>` and signed in with my sandbox account. It shows me the usual payment window but when I pressed the "Continue" button, it tried to redirect to the return page but instead, refreshed the page itself.

When I tryed to check the order using `rel:self`'s link: `GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>`. It correctly showed the sandbox account's shipping details (name and address), but the `status` remained `CREATED` (not `APPROVED` or `COMPLETED`):

```json
{
    "id": "<random-id>",
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "reference_id": "default",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "10.00"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "<payee-email>",
                "merchant_id": "<payee-id>"
            },
            "shipping": {
                "name": {
                    "full_name": "<payer-name>"
                },
                "address": {
                    "address_line_1": "<payer-address-1>",
                    "address_line_2": "<payer-address-2>",
                    "admin_area_2": "<payer-address-3>",
                    "admin_area_1": "<payer-address-4>",
                    "postal_code": "<payer-address-5>",
                    "country_code": "<payer-address-6>"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "create_time": "<time-of-post-request>",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=<random-id>",
            "rel": "approve",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>",
            "rel": "update",
            "method": "PATCH"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>/capture",
            "rel": "capture",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I tried to capture the payment using `rel:caputure`'s link: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/<random-id>/capture` with header `Content Type: application/json` and empty body, it said "payer has not approved the Order for payment", despite I getting the shipping details from the `GET` request before:

```json
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details": [
        {
            "issue": "ORDER_NOT_APPROVED",
            "description": "Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment. Please redirect the payer to the 'rel':'approve' url returned as part of the HATEOAS links within the Create Order call or provide a valid payment_source in the request."
        }
    ],
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "6a10ea489ffce",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ORDER_NOT_APPROVED",
            "rel": "information_link",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have three questions:

1. Was I using the Orders API correctly? Did I miss some HTTP requests and/or some crucial steps?
2. I had the return URL set for my sandbox application, why did the payment page not redirect me but instead refreshed itself? Did I miss some setup beforehand?
3. Why did I fail to capture the payment like above?

P.S. After some digging I think I might be missing the [authorize payment step](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_authorize) but I have no idea how to do it. (Client-side request? Server-side request?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I proceeded to `rel:approve`'s link .. when I pressed the "Continue" button, it tried to redirect to the return page but instead, refreshed the page itself.

You did not specify a return_url , so there is nowhere to return to. Refreshing is all that can be done.

What you should do is not redirect to an approval URL, and integrate *with no redirects*. For this make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score 0):

I was also having trouble with this issue, I solved it by expanding the request body, much like @preston-phx said, with the return URL, and it looked something like this:

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "payer": {
      "email_address": requestBody.payer_email
    },
    "purchase_units": [{
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": requestBody.amount
      },
      "payee": {
        "email_address": requestBody.payee_email
      },
      "payment_instruction": {
        "disbursement_mode": "INSTANT",  // can be INSTANT or DELAYED
        "platform_fees": [
          {
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": calculateFeesFromAmount(requestBody.amount)
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }],
    "redirect_urls": {
      "return_url": "https://example.com/paypalpay/order/approved",
      "cancel_url": "https://example.com/paypalpay/order/cancelled"
    },
    "application_context": {
      "brand_name": "Header for payment page",
      "locale": "en-US",
      "landing_page": "BILLING", // can be NO_PREFERENCE, LOGIN, BILLING
      "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING" // because I didn't want shipping info on the page,
      "user_action": "PAY_NOW",  // Button name, can be PAY_NOW or CONTINUE
      "return_url": "https://example.com/paypalpay/order/approved",
      "cancel_url": "https://example.com/paypalpay/order/cancelled"
    }
  }
```

This also helped me customise the payment page to an extent. I hope Paypal folks include these in the docs at the correct places, most of devs have to dig through a lot of documentation to create an extensive, usable request body.